# Testing Template Reference Variable in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I have the following code:

```
<input class="txt-port-id" id="portId"
     [value]="portIdFund1"
     maxlength="4"
     size="4"
     (keyup)="fundPortIdChanged(fund1PortId.value, 'fund1')"
     #fund1Port>
```

Angular docs says [passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice), thus passing template reference variable. How do we write Unit Test in Jasmine for the same?

Comment: Do you want unit test for the above snippet of code ?

Comment: Yes, not sure what would be the approach. Tried with triggerEventHandler but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) in the following way:

```
it('simple input test', fakeAsync(() => {
      const fundChangedSpy = spyOn(component, 'fundPortIdChanged').and.callThrough();
      const portIDInput: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#portId');
      expect(portIDInput.value).toEqual('');
      portIDInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(50);
      expect(portIDInput.value).toEqual('fund1');
      expect(fundChangedSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

However as I understand it's more encouraged to use [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of [Template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms) with unit testing.

> Reactive forms also provide a straightforward path to testing because you are assured that your data is consistent and predictable when requested. Any consumers of the streams have access to manipulate that data safely.

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-template-driven-test-example) with the test.